# Adding "System.Data.SQLite" as a reference

Tags: system.data.sqlite

when I was building my project done in ASP.NET and C#, it produced the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?"

So, when I tried to add it as a reference, I was not able to find "System.Data.SQLite" in my library.

How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to search for System.Data.SQLite.DLL file (using windows explorer search) or if you have not yet installed it just download it from the net.

For more information try to read [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20100208133236/http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/).

Answer (score 8):

You get it (as a dll), then add a reference to it.

[download here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/)

for example install to C:\Program Files\SQLite.NET and browse to:

C:\Program Files\SQLite.NET\bin

Comment: it looks like you can add this via nuget package manager now, although I haven't tried it out. "System.Data.SQLite" v1.0.98.1 perhaps... which is also newer than those in the above download.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLite.NET\bin (if you have a 64bit System)

Answer (score 7):

I found that the best way to do this is to enter the following into the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package System.Data.SqLite
```

Answer (score 3):

For those folks that downloaded SQLite but can't get the DLL to show up in VS2010:

I've downloaded the latest SQLite build for my environment, but I still couldn't get the DLL to show up under References> Add Reference> .Net tab.

To fix this, I went into the Add Reference Window and selected the Browse Tab and just browsed to the DLL file in the install directory\bin folder. Now it shows up fine.

Answer (score -1):

You need to [download System.Data.SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=132486), then you can add it to your project.