# Cannot Import System.Data.SQLite VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, visual-studio-2010

Running Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10

I downloaded and installed sqlite-netFx40-setup-x86-2010-1.0.104.0.exe

My project is set to use .NET Framework 4.0

I added the reference to the System.Data.Sqlite.dll file just downloaded. (I tried it with and without CopyLocal)

I added the following lines in my app.config / system.data / DbProviderfactories section file per the readme file:

```
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
         type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
```

In any code file, I can add the Imports System.Data.Sqlite command and make a variable of type SQLiteConnection. e.g:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SQLite

''' <summary>
''' Provides Methods for parsing info from a SQLite
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class ParseSQLite
    Public Shared Function GetDatabaseVersion(ConnectionString As String) As String
        Dim connection As SQLiteConnection
        ...
        Return ""
    End Function
End Class
```

This works fine with no immediate errors until my first build. I then get the error "Type 'SQLiteConnection' is not defined.

I also looked at another SO Question
[Adding “System.Data.SQLite” as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399520/adding-system-data-sqlite-as-a-reference/%22Adding%20'System.Data.SQLite'%20as%20a%20reference%22) 
but it is wasn't relevant since I could add the reference without issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: `...the System.Data.Sqlite.dll file just downloaded` if you add it as a NuGet package, it configures everything in the project for you.

Comment: First try using a fully qualified class name `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection` and see if that works. If not, probably an issue with the reference or namespaces

Comment: Also ensure `Copy Local` is `True` for your reference, so the DLL is available to the compiled EXE.

Answer (score 1):

that don't work anymore(or it has a bug), the only way i found is via NUget.
[VS 2010 NUGET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x1wz.jpg)

you can read here on installing NUGet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget

scroll down until you see the "NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio"